# Make NumLock default

Tags: keyboard, numlock

I would like to make NumLock default.

I follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock

However, In the settings I cannot find anything called "Keyboard Preferences". I am working in Ubuntu 20.04.

Can you please help?

Comment: I have no gnome anymore is `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state
` is this key available?

Comment: @nobody, I get the response `"No such key “numlock-state”"`